# 行と列の時系列統合の問題

Tags: python, python3, pandas

以下のデータフレームがあります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

A列を削除して、Bの日付と1行の時間を統合したいです：
このような感じ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

プログラミングコードは以下となります。

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"ファイル.csv", header=None, encoding='shift-jis')
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['日付'] + ' ' + df.columns[2].replace('24:00', '00:00'), errors='coerce')
result_df = df.melt(id_vars=['datetime'], value_vars=df.columns[3:], var_name='time', value_name='flow')
result_df['time'] = result_df['time'].replace('24:00', '00:00')
result_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(result_df['time'], format='%H:%M').dt.time
result_df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(result_df['datetime'].dt.date.astype(str) + ' ' + result_df['time'].astype(str), errors='coerce')
result_df['datetime'] = result_df['datetime'] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)
result_df = result_df.sort_values(by=['datetime']).reset_index(drop=True)
result_df = result_df[['datetime', 'flow']]
print(result_df.head())
```

出力の結果は以下になります。

```
             datetime flow
0 2021-04-01 00:30:00   8992
1 2021-04-01 01:30:00   8238
2 2021-04-01 02:00:00   8412
3 2021-04-01 02:30:00   8145
4 2021-04-01 03:00:00   8148
```

正しい結果は

```
             datetime flow
0 2021-04-01 00:30:00   9481
1 2021-04-01 01:30:00   8238
2 2021-04-01 02:00:00   8412
3 2021-04-01 02:30:00   8145
4 2021-04-01 03:00:00   8148
```

どう書き換えたらいいですか？
ご教授頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> このような感じ

```py
dfx = df.iloc[:,1:].drop(df.index[0]).rename(columns=df.iloc[0])\
        .set_index('日付').stack().reset_index()
date_time = pd.to_datetime(dfx.iloc[:,:2].agg(' '.join, axis=1), errors='coerce')
date_time = date_time.fillna(date_time.shift().add(pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)))
dfx = pd.concat([date_time, dfx[0]], axis=1).set_axis(['datetime', 'flow'], axis=1)

print(dfx)
```

| datetime | flow |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:30:00 | 9481 |
| 2021-01-01 01:00:00 | 8238 |
| 2021-01-01 01:30:00 | 8412 |
| 2021-01-01 02:00:00 | 8145 |
| 2021-01-01 02:30:00 | 8148 |
| 2021-01-01 03:00:00 | 8808 |
| 2021-01-01 22:00:00 | 8688 |
| 2021-01-01 22:30:00 | 9510 |
| 2021-01-01 23:00:00 | 9438 |
| 2021-01-01 23:30:00 | 8117 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 8992 |
| 2021-01-02 00:30:00 | 8685 |
| 2021-01-02 01:00:00 | 8130 |
| 2021-01-02 01:30:00 | 9463 |
| 2021-01-02 02:00:00 | 9176 |
| 2021-01-02 02:30:00 | 8009 |
| 2021-01-02 03:00:00 | 8033 |
| 2021-01-02 22:00:00 | 8337 |
| 2021-01-02 22:30:00 | 9195 |
| 2021-01-02 23:00:00 | 8337 |
| 2021-01-02 23:30:00 | 8125 |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 8932 |
| 2021-01-03 00:30:00 | 8514 |
| 2021-01-03 01:00:00 | 9196 |
| 2021-01-03 01:30:00 | 8540 |
| 2021-01-03 02:00:00 | 8645 |
| 2021-01-03 02:30:00 | 9841 |
| 2021-01-03 03:00:00 | 8596 |
| 2021-01-03 22:00:00 | 8548 |
| 2021-01-03 22:30:00 | 8249 |
| 2021-01-03 23:00:00 | 8339 |
| 2021-01-03 23:30:00 | 9379 |
| 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 8438 |

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。追加質問ですが、以前も聞いたことがありますけど、
日付のフォーマットはこう 2021/1/1 0:30 2021/8/1 1:00 2021/1/1 1:00 2021/1/1 1:30にしたいなら、df1.index = df1.index.strftime('%Y/%#m/%#d %#H:%M') 
はdfx = pd.concat([date_time, dfx[0]], axis=1).set_axis(['datetime', 'flow'], axis=1)の前に入れますか？

Comment: 今回は Series 型ですので、`date_time = date_time.dt.strftime('%Y/%#m/%#d %#H:%M')` としてみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。